# How Does Laravel 8 Polymorphic Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-relations, polymorphic-relationship

**Laravel Hospital Management System Table Relation With Prescription, Presscription_medicine and Medicine Table.**

> the concept is presscription_medicine table's store more medicine by
> reference one prescription  id, and each presscription_medicine row's
> has medicine in , then in presscription_medicine table's medicine id
> relation with medicine table.
>
> how to do this relations, and how to get medicine name in prescription
> table output as like this

[image]

**I have already tired for this.**

```
Prescription Migration table 
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePrescriptionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('prescriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('prescription_code', 45);
            $table->string('prescription_p_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('prescription_doc_id');
            $table->string('prescription_history', 220);
            $table->string('prescription_note', 220);
            $table->string('prescription_date',45);
            $table->timestamps();
           // $table->foreign('prescription_p_id');
            //->references('in_p_s', 'out_p_id')->on('in_patients', 'out_patients')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('prescription_doc_id')->references('id')->on('doctors');
            //->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('prescriptions');
    }
}
```

**Prescription_medicine table**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePrescriptionMedicinesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('prescription__medicines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('prescription_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('prescription_medicine_id');
            $table->string('prescription_med_dosage', 45);
            $table->string('prescription_med_frequency', 45);
            $table->string('prescription_med_days', 45);
            $table->string('prescription_med_ins', 45);
            $table->timestamps();
            
            $table->foreign('prescription_id')->references('id')->on('prescriptions')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('prescription_medicine_id')->references('id')->on('medicines')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('prescription__medicines');
    }
}
```

**Medicine Table**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateMedicinesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('medicines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('price');
            $table->integer('mg');
            $table->string('group');
            $table->string('company');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('medicines');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Prescription Model class add this relation method:

```
public function medicines()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Medicine::class,'prescription__medicines');
}
```

Comment: then when I show datatable from Prescription table by loop,
how I show Medicine Name ?